# Swagger..Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not specify a valid version field. Django Server

Tags: django, swagger, openapi

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

It works locally but it shows above given error on server. For reference screenshot is attached.[dj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyjnR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Swagger Yaml file asking for supported versions. Although version is given but still error is there.